# The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard

I am getting this error when i m tring to validate my app before submit it to mac app store by using xcode 4.2

While when i m trying to upload app from xcode 4.3 it is fit and fine.

Will it might be possible app uploaded from mac so x 10.7 will not be compatible to 10.6.

Why this error come?

Comment: "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor" as it says in the question title.

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423575/submitting-a-mac-app-fails-with-bad-file-descriptor