# Attempt to sign iOS app fails with error 'Bad File Descriptor'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I attempted a process I've done successfully several times. I Archive my app. The Organizer pops up. I click on "Distribute", select the identity I want to sign with and click "Export". Normally I then select where I want to save my Archive but instead I get an error "The operation couldn't be completed. Bad file descriptor."

I've done my research here on stackoverflow ([Submitting a Mac App fails with 'Bad File Descriptor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423575/submitting-a-mac-app-fails-with-bad-file-descriptor)) and other forums and everyone suggests that X-Code itself is corrupted and that I should execute a few terminal commands to install the components I need, or that I should re-install X-Code itself. However, since I downloaded X-Code as a complete package directly from the app store the former is not an option, and I've tried re-installing X-Code about 5 times now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why I was getting this message. However deleting X-Code yet again, restarting my computer, and downloading X-Code from the Apple developer site instead of the App store seemed to solve the problem.