# Bad file descriptor Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: xcode

Swift 3 - 
Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002)
 - Archiving iPhone App

I have this message when I try to archive my app :

> (Xcode) encountered read error on command output pipe (Bad file descriptor)

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423575/submitting-a-mac-app-fails-with-bad-file-descriptor)  but it doesn't work.

Comment: Archiving or submitting?

Comment: Archiving as I mentioned in the post

Comment: No, you had "submitting". Okay, so this sounds like a problem with your hard disk. Maybe you are running out of disk space? Or there's an issue with the disk catalog? But that would not be a Stack Overflow problem. You should ask on SuperUser or AskDifferent.

Comment: Yes I cleaned my mistake. Thanks I'm gonna try on AskDifferent

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267152/bad-file-descriptor-xcode-8-2-1
Considered as off topic for AskDifferent...